# Processing log file using Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match multiple log entries *per line*.
Every entry is in proceeding format:

```
instance      Role      id          [state] [flags] [activity]     [status]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
30:9876543210 Secondary 1122334455           V       InTransition
10:0123456789 Primary   9874563210  IB       EV                     FDown
```

Items between square brackets are optional, while others are mandatory, and they are `space` separated.

Regex that I wrote, doesn't work as intended, there is a particular case, that I discovered so far, where match fails.

**Current regex:** `(?<instance>\d+:\d+) (?<role>[a-zA-Z]+) (?<id>\d+)\s?(?<state>SB|IB|RD|DD)?\s?(?<flags>[A-Z]+)?\s(?<activity>InTransition|Down|Up)?\s?(?<other>[a-zA-Z]+)?`

**Entry that fails:** `30:9876543210 Secondary 1122334455 IB InTransition`

| Result | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| instance: 30:9876543210 | instance: 30:9876543210 |
| role: Secondary | role: Secondary |
| id: 1122334455 | id: 1122334455 |
| state: IB | state: IB |
| **flags: I** | **flags:** |
| **activity:** | **activity: InTransition** |
| **other: nTransition** | **other:** |

There is probably much better solution than mine, even if you have a slightest clue how to fix regex that I wrote or you have your own, please feel free to comment. Thank you.

**Edit:**
[Here is a RegExr link with a few examples](https://regexr.com/5p2dp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<instance>\d+:\d+) (?<role>[a-zA-Z]+) (?<service_id>\d+)(?:\s(?<state>SB|IB|RD|DD))?(?:\s(?<flags>[A-Z]+)\b)?(?:\s(?<activity>InTransition|Down|Up))?(?:\s(?<other>[a-zA-Z]+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tJUO8/1/).

There are two important bits here:

- The parts that are optional should represent optional occurrences of obligatory pattern sequences. Note you have sequences of optional patterns, e.g. `\s?(?<flags>[A-Z]+)?`. They all can match an empty string before a non-matching pattern and you would still receive a match. When you use `(?:\s(?<flags>[A-Z]+))?`, you match an optional occurrence of an obligatory (one) whitespace and one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- The `flags` part should be matched as a whole word. Hence, it should look like `(?:\s(?<flags>[A-Z]+)\b)?`.